# How to organize large number of objects in cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for suggestions on how to organize large number of objects.

Assuming the incoming rate is about 60,000,000 files per day and I would like to keep them for 180 days.

With hourly partition, there will be 4320 (24 * 180) directories at the top level. And each directory will contain ~2,500,000 files on average.

If I only need to fetch the files individually by its full path and I do not need to list the content of the directory, is there any issue with leaving all 2500000 of them in the same level?

Or should I hash the filenames and store them in multiple sub directories? (like how it's typically done if stored on a traditional file system)

Answer (score 5):

There's no limit on the number of objects you can store in a bucket, and breaking objects into more "subdirectories" doesn't make any scalability or performance difference. To the Google Cloud Storage service all object names are flat: the "/" in the path just looks like any other character in the object name.

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage Team

Comment: This answer is no longer current. Avoid using sequential object names such as timestamp-based object names if you are uploading many objects in parallel. Objects with sequential names are stored consecutively, so they are likely to hit the same backend server. When this happens, throughput is constrained. In order to achieve optimal throughput, add the hash of the sequence number as part of the object name to make it non-sequential. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming