# Does Google Cloud Storage need to optimize the key prefix for speed like AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

In AWS S3, it is recommended to optimize the key prefix to avoid hotspot,

e.g.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Is it also required or recommended for Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to organize large number of objects in cloud storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905701/how-to-organize-large-number-of-objects-in-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905976/624900):

> breaking objects into more "subdirectories" doesn't make any scalability or performance difference

More concretely, the name of an object does not effect the performance or scalability of accessing objects in the bucket.